# Complete a positional argument only once

Tags: autocomplete, arguments, fish

I'm trying to write a completion for a command (call it `gs`) that takes an SSH hostname as its first argument, and an arbitrary string as the second argument.

I've stolen this from the default SSH completion:

```
# Load completions shared by various ssh tools like ssh, scp and sftp.
__fish_complete_ssh ssh
# Also retrieve `user@host` entries from history
function __ssh_history_completions
    history --prefix ssh --max=100 | string replace -rf '.* ([A-Za-z0-9._:-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._:-]+).*' '$1'
end
```

And I use it to complete the arguments to my `gs` command:

```
complete -c gs -d Remote -xa "(__fish_complete_user_at_hosts)"
complete -c gs -d Remote -ka '(__ssh_history_completions)'
```

This works, but it completes SSH hostnames for *both arguments*:

- if I type `gs <tab>`, fish correctly completes SSH hostnames,
- if I type `gs somehost <tab>`, fish incorrectly completes SSH hostnames again (this argument should just not be completed, it's an arbitrary string).

How can I make this completion only affect the *first* positional argument to my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--condition` or `-n` option to `complete`, with the helper function `__fish_is_first_arg`:

```
complete -c gs -d Remote -xa "(__fish_complete_user_at_hosts)" -n '__fish_is_first_arg'
```

Comment: `__fish_is_first_arg` [was removed](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8008), but there's now `__fish_is_first_token` (and `__fish_is_nth_token`). c.f. [the repository at the time of writing this comment](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/tree/bc29b4aee19a96d2a5a98b1912d660f31247e2ca/share/functions).